# Symfony authentication after signin

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm installing the signin of symfony. I follow this instruction :
http://donna-oberes.blogspot.be/2013/09/user-login-and-logout-step-by-step-with.html.

Now I want after the form is valid and data is saved in database, the user can be authenticated without redirect to login form. As a result they can skip the step to fill to username, password of login form.

Here my security.yml configure. I use the default authentication of symfony
[image]